# Gitlab CI CD Pipeline Variable Concat Two Variables Not Working

Tags: gitlab, cicd

The Problem: I am trying to concat two variables for a copy cmd in a before script for a gitlab ci/cd pipeline job.

What I expect: myfile_filesuffix
What I get: _filesuffix

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? When I run this for loop on my local CLI I have no problems. Thank you!

```
before_script:
  - rm -rf .terraform
  - terraform --version
  - mkdir ~/.aws
  - echo "[default]" > ~/.aws/credentials 
  - echo "aws_access_key_id=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" >>  ~/.aws/credentials
  - echo "aws_secret_access_key=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" >>  ~/.aws/credentials
  - mkdir ./deployments
  - ls common
  - common_files=$(find common -type f)
  - echo $common_files
  - prefix_common=$(echo $common_files | cut -d"/" -f 1)
  - echo $prefix_common
  - for f in $common_files;
      do 
       common_file="$(basename $f)"
       cp $f ./deployments/""${common_file}"_"${prefix_common}"";
      done
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: The code I executed is below the image. I am put the image just to show how gitlab was executing the code and the output

Comment: Which could have been copied and pasted into the question as text, instead of an image. Images should be used only when there is no other way to demonstrate an issue, which is not the case with text output. Read the post I linked, please.

Answer (score 0):

you can used GitLab repo settings -> CI/CD -> Variables to add FILE type variable and use mv command move to your folder.

ex: File Type variable is ANSIBLE_VARIABLES_FILE

```
script:
    - mv $ANSIBLE_VARIABLES_FILE ./deployments/variables_common.tf
```